# NEPLAN Load Flow Analysis with 1-day measurement

Tags: energy, power-engineering, analysis

currently I am working on a project to identify energy loses in an electrical network. I am using NEPLAN 10, and already build a small system and implemented measurements. As soon as start the calculations, I get a few values, but the graphical interface doesn't fit at all. So I am not sure whether everything is working properly or not.
Could someone help with working with NEPLAN, and have a look together?

Comment: Show links and issues

Comment: Insufficient info and probably you ought to consult youtube then OEM.